# IllegalStateException: stableCount < 0: -1 on writing to device database

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-contentresolver

In my app I write messages to internal device database with following code :
`context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);`

Some users (currently only on Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.2) reported the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: stableCount < 0: -1
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.refContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2596)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.releaseProvider(ActivityThread.java:4608)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.releaseProvider(ContextImpl.java:1997)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:875)
```

I could not find any hint why this Exception will be thrown, neither what it means. Is there anything I can do to avoid this (except catching it) or can someone explain what this means?

Thanks in advance,
Danny

Comment: I have a similar issue and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I meet a similar issue(java.lang.IllegalStateException: stableCount < 0: -1) but a bit different from yours, my fault is call Cursor.close() for twice times.

For IContentProvider.insert call throw a exception, it leads to call releaseProvider(provider);
so we should first find why IContentProvider.insert throw a exception.

```
 public final Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues values)
{
    IContentProvider provider = acquireProvider(url);
    if (provider == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + url);
    }
    try {
        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Uri createdRow = provider.insert(mPackageName, url, values);
        long durationMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        maybeLogUpdateToEventLog(durationMillis, url, "insert", null /* where */);
        return createdRow;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // Arbitrary and not worth documenting, as Activity
        // Manager will kill this process shortly anyway.
        return null;
    } finally {
        releaseProvider(provider);
    }
}
```